# Unusual behaviour with PyTorch transformer decoder layer

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, transformer-model

I was turning the decoder model code with pytorch transformer decoder layer and I am getting different loss even though I tried to match the implementation and the tokens are getting repetitive when using the pytorch transformer decoder layer rather the from scratch

The code below the the correct implementation of the decoder

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn import functional as F

# hyperparameters
batch_size = 16 # how many independent sequences will we process in parallel?
block_size = 32 # what is the maximum context length for predictions?
max_iters = 5000
eval_interval = 100
learning_rate = 1e-3
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
eval_iters = 200
n_embd = 64
n_head = 4
n_layer = 4
dropout = 0.0
# ------------

torch.manual_seed(1337)

# wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karpathy/char-rnn/master/data/tinyshakespeare/input.txt
with open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

# here are all the unique characters that occur in this text
chars = sorted(list(set(text)))
vocab_size = len(chars)
# create a mapping from characters to integers
stoi = { ch:i for i,ch in enumerate(chars) }
itos = { i:ch for i,ch in enumerate(chars) }
encode = lambda s: [stoi[c] for c in s] # encoder: take a string, output a list of integers
decode = lambda l: ''.join([itos[i] for i in l]) # decoder: take a list of integers, output a string

# Train and test splits
data = torch.tensor(encode(text), dtype=torch.long)
n = int(0.9*len(data)) # first 90% will be train, rest val
train_data = data[:n]
val_data = data[n:]

# data loading
def get_batch(split):
    # generate a small batch of data of inputs x and targets y
    data = train_data if split == 'train' else val_data
    ix = torch.randint(len(data) - block_size, (batch_size,))
    x = torch.stack([data[i:i+block_size] for i in ix])
    y = torch.stack([data[i+1:i+block_size+1] for i in ix])
    x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)
    return x, y

u/torch.no_grad()
def estimate_loss():
    out = {}
    model.eval()
    for split in ['train', 'val']:
        losses = torch.zeros(eval_iters)
        for k in range(eval_iters):
            X, Y = get_batch(split)
            logits, loss = model(X, Y)
            losses[k] = loss.item()
        out[split] = losses.mean()
    model.train()
    return out

class Head(nn.Module):
    """ one head of self-attention """

    def __init__(self, head_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.key = nn.Linear(n_embd, head_size, bias=False)
        self.query = nn.Linear(n_embd, head_size, bias=False)
        self.value = nn.Linear(n_embd, head_size, bias=False)
        self.register_buffer('tril', torch.tril(torch.ones(block_size, block_size)))

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, x):
        B,T,C = x.shape
        k = self.key(x)   # (B,T,C)
        q = self.query(x) # (B,T,C)
        # compute attention scores ("affinities")
        wei = q @ k.transpose(-2,-1) * C**-0.5 # (B, T, C) @ (B, C, T) -> (B, T, T)
        wei = wei.masked_fill(self.tril[:T, :T] == 0, float('-inf')) # (B, T, T)
        wei = F.softmax(wei, dim=-1) # (B, T, T)
        wei = self.dropout(wei)
        # perform the weighted aggregation of the values
        v = self.value(x) # (B,T,C)
        out = wei @ v # (B, T, T) @ (B, T, C) -> (B, T, C)
        return out

class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    """ multiple heads of self-attention in parallel """

    def __init__(self, num_heads, head_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.heads = nn.ModuleList([Head(head_size) for _ in range(num_heads)])
        self.proj = nn.Linear(n_embd, n_embd)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = torch.cat([h(x) for h in self.heads], dim=-1)
        out = self.dropout(self.proj(out))
        return out

class FeedFoward(nn.Module):
    """ a simple linear layer followed by a non-linearity """

    def __init__(self, n_embd):
        super().__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(n_embd, 4 * n_embd),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(4 * n_embd, n_embd),
            nn.Dropout(dropout),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net(x)

class Block(nn.Module):
    """ Transformer block: communication followed by computation """

    def __init__(self, n_embd, n_head):
        # n_embd: embedding dimension, n_head: the number of heads we'd like
        super().__init__()
        head_size = n_embd // n_head
        self.sa = MultiHeadAttention(n_head, head_size)
        self.ffwd = FeedFoward(n_embd)
        self.ln1 = nn.LayerNorm(n_embd)
        self.ln2 = nn.LayerNorm(n_embd)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x + self.sa(self.ln1(x))
        x = x + self.ffwd(self.ln2(x))
        return x

# super simple bigram model
class TransformerDecoder(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # each token directly reads off the logits for the next token from a lookup table
        self.token_embedding_table = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, n_embd)
        self.position_embedding_table = nn.Embedding(block_size, n_embd)
        self.blocks = nn.Sequential(*[Block(n_embd, n_head=n_head) for _ in range(n_layer)])
        self.ln_f = nn.LayerNorm(n_embd) # final layer norm
        self.lm_head = nn.Linear(n_embd, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, idx, targets=None):
        B, T = idx.shape

        # idx and targets are both (B,T) tensor of integers
        tok_emb = self.token_embedding_table(idx) # (B,T,C)
        pos_emb = self.position_embedding_table(torch.arange(T, device=device)) # (T,C)
        x = tok_emb + pos_emb # (B,T,C)
        x = self.blocks(x) # (B,T,C)
        x = self.ln_f(x) # (B,T,C)
        logits = self.lm_head(x) # (B,T,vocab_size)

        if targets is None:
            loss = None
        else:
            B, T, C = logits.shape
            logits = logits.view(B*T, C)
            targets = targets.view(B*T)
            loss = F.cross_entropy(logits, targets)

        return logits, loss

    def generate(self, idx, max_new_tokens):
        # idx is (B, T) array of indices in the current context
        for _ in range(max_new_tokens):
            # crop idx to the last block_size tokens
            idx_cond = idx[:, -block_size:]
            # get the predictions
            logits, loss = self(idx_cond)
            # focus only on the last time step
            logits = logits[:, -1, :] # becomes (B, C)
            # apply softmax to get probabilities
            probs = F.softmax(logits, dim=-1) # (B, C)
            # sample from the distribution
            idx_next = torch.multinomial(probs, num_samples=1) # (B, 1)
            # append sampled index to the running sequence
            idx = torch.cat((idx, idx_next), dim=1) # (B, T+1)
        return idx

model = TransformerDecoder()
m = model.to(device)
# print the number of parameters in the model
print(sum(p.numel() for p in m.parameters())/1e6, 'M parameters')

# create a PyTorch optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for iter in range(max_iters):

    # every once in a while evaluate the loss on train and val sets
    if iter % eval_interval == 0 or iter == max_iters - 1:
        losses = estimate_loss()
        print(f"step {iter}: train loss {losses['train']:.4f}, val loss {losses['val']:.4f}")

    # sample a batch of data
    xb, yb = get_batch('train')

    # evaluate the loss
    logits, loss = model(xb, yb)
    optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

# generate from the model
context = torch.zeros((1, 1), dtype=torch.long, device=device)
print(decode(m.generate(context, max_new_tokens=2000)[0].tolist()))
```

0.203279 M parameters
step 0: train loss 3.0684, val loss 3.0634
step 100: train loss 0.9685, val loss 0.9290
step 200: train loss 0.6753, val loss 0.6564
step 300: train loss 0.5599, val loss 0.5882
step 400: train loss 0.3871, val loss 0.5186
step 500: train loss 0.2547, val loss 0.3679
step 600: train loss 0.2038, val loss 0.2841
step 700: train loss 0.1839, val loss 0.2364
step 800: train loss 0.1704, val loss 0.2210
step 900: train loss 0.1627, val loss 0.2135
step 1000: train loss 0.1568, val loss 0.1984

This is the implementation with TransformerDecoder Layer with pytorch and I have problem with this implementation

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn import functional as F

# hyperparameters
batch_size = 16  # how many independent sequences will we process in parallel?
block_size = 32  # what is the maximum context length for predictions?
max_iters = 1000
eval_interval = 100
learning_rate = 1e-3
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
eval_iters = 200
n_embd = 64
n_head = 4
n_layer = 4
dropout = 0.0
# ------------

torch.manual_seed(1337)

# Assuming input.txt is already downloaded and available
with open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

# here are all the unique characters that occur in this text
chars = sorted(list(set(text)))
vocab_size = len(chars)
# create a mapping from characters to integers
stoi = {ch: i for i, ch in enumerate(chars)}
itos = {i: ch for i, ch in enumerate(chars)}
encode = lambda s: [stoi[c] for c in s]  # encoder: take a string, output a list of integers
decode = lambda l: ''.join([itos[i] for i in l])  # decoder: take a list of integers, output a string

# Train and test splits
data = torch.tensor(encode(text), dtype=torch.long)
n = int(0.9 * len(data))  # first 90% will be train, rest val
train_data = data[:n]
val_data = data[n:]

# data loading
def get_batch(split):
    # generate a small batch of data of inputs x and targets y
    data = train_data if split == 'train' else val_data
    ix = torch.randint(len(data) - block_size, (batch_size,))
    x = torch.stack([data[i:i + block_size] for i in ix])
    y = torch.stack([data[i + 1:i + block_size + 1] for i in ix])
    x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)
    return x, y

u/torch.no_grad()
def estimate_loss():
    out = {}
    model.eval()
    for split in ['train', 'val']:
        losses = torch.zeros(eval_iters)
        for k in range(eval_iters):
            X, Y = get_batch(split)
            logits, loss = model(X, Y)
            losses[k] = loss.item()
        out[split] = losses.mean()
    model.train()
    return out

class TransformerDecoderModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, n_embd, n_head, n_layer, block_size, dropout=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.n_embd = n_embd
        self.n_head = n_head
        self.n_layer = n_layer
        self.block_size = block_size

        self.token_embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, n_embd)
        self.position_embedding = nn.Embedding(block_size, n_embd)

        decoder_layer = nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(d_model=n_embd, nhead=n_head, dropout=dropout)
        self.transformer_decoder = nn.TransformerDecoder(decoder_layer, num_layers=n_layer)

        self.ln_f = nn.LayerNorm(n_embd)  # Final LayerNorm
        self.lm_head = nn.Linear(n_embd, vocab_size, bias=False)

    def generate_square_subsequent_mask(self, sz):
        mask = torch.triu(torch.ones(sz, sz) * float('-inf'), diagonal=1)
        return mask

    def forward(self, idx, targets=None):
        B, T = idx.shape
        device = idx.device

        # Create mask with shape [block_size, block_size]
        mask = self.generate_square_subsequent_mask(T).to(device)

        tok_emb = self.token_embedding(idx)  # [B, T, C]
        pos_emb = self.position_embedding(torch.arange(T, dtype=torch.long, device=device))  # [T, C]
        pos_emb = pos_emb.unsqueeze(0).repeat(B, 1, 1)  # Expand to match batch size: [B, T, C]
        x = tok_emb + pos_emb

        # Transformer requires input shape as [T, B, C]
        x = x.permute(1, 0, 2)  # [T, B, C]
        x = self.transformer_decoder(x, x, tgt_mask=mask)

        # Revert shape to [B, T, C] for the linear layer
        x = x.permute(1, 0, 2)

        x = self.ln_f(x)
        logits = self.lm_head(x)

        if targets is not None:
            loss = F.cross_entropy(logits.view(-1, self.vocab_size), targets.view(-1))
            return logits, loss
        else:
            return logits, None

    def generate(self, idx, max_new_tokens):
        idx = idx.to(device)
        for _ in range(max_new_tokens):
            idx_cond = idx[:, -self.block_size:]
            logits = self.forward(idx_cond)[0]
            probs = F.softmax(logits[:, -1, :], dim=-1)
            idx_next = torch.multinomial(probs, num_samples=1)
            idx = torch.cat([idx, idx_next], dim=1)
        return idx


model = TransformerDecoderModel(vocab_size=vocab_size, n_embd=n_embd, n_head=n_head, n_layer=n_layer, block_size=block_size, dropout=dropout)

m = model.to(device)
# print the number of parameters in the model
print(sum(p.numel() for p in m.parameters())/1e6, 'M parameters')

# create a PyTorch optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for iter in range(max_iters):

    # every once in a while evaluate the loss on train and val sets
    if iter % eval_interval == 0 or iter == max_iters - 1:
        losses = estimate_loss()
        print(f"step {iter}: train loss {losses['train']:.4f}, val loss {losses['val']:.4f}")

    # sample a batch of data
    xb, yb = get_batch('train')

    # evaluate the loss
    logits, loss = model(xb, yb)
    optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

# generate from the model
context = torch.zeros((1, 1), dtype=torch.long, device=device)
print(decode(m.generate(context, max_new_tokens=2000)[0].tolist()))
```

step 0: train loss 3.1871, val loss 3.2023
step 100: train loss 0.9042, val loss 0.8612
step 200: train loss 0.1210, val loss 0.1222
step 300: train loss 0.0269, val loss 0.0262
step 400: train loss 0.0178, val loss 0.0231
step 500: train loss 0.0153, val loss 0.0221
step 600: train loss 0.0072, val loss 0.0173
step 700: train loss 0.0110, val loss 0.0102
step 800: train loss 0.0027, val loss 0.0041
step 900: train loss 0.0019, val loss 0.0015
step 999: train loss 0.0006, val loss 0.0006

even though I implemented one thing form scratch and the other with transformer decoder layers both loss is different and I see PyTorch transformer decoder implementation wrong as its generating same token repeatedly why?